# NullPointerException when using EditText

Tags: java, android

I have the following function that i call from 2 different functions. the first way i call all is correct, the second way i get the following NullPointerException.
any idea why ?

```
private void doSearch(View v) {

    Activity activity = getActivity();
    //get the text:
    EditText editSearch = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editSearch);
    String query =  editSearch.getText().toString();
    //check if 2 letters were entered for search
    if (query.length()>1){
        //call service with extra
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, SearchPlacesService.class);
        intent.putExtra("query", query);            
        activity.startService(intent);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter 2 letters for search", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}



    //good call
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.editSearch:
        doSearch(v);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


//unsuccessful  call
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnSearch:
        doSearch((TextView) v);
        break;      
    }
}
```

the Logcat:

```
01-07 09:29:08.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1078): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-07 09:29:08.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1078): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-07 09:29:08.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at com.lora_solomon.myfavoriteplaces.view.FragmentList.doSearch(FragmentList.java:137)
01-07 09:29:08.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at com.lora_solomon.myfavoriteplaces.view.FragmentList.onClick(FragmentList.java:100)
01-07 09:29:08.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
01-07 09:29:08.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
01-07 09:29:08.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-07 09:29:08.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-07 09:29:08.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-07 09:29:08.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-07 09:29:08.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-07 09:29:08.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-07 09:29:08.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-07 09:29:08.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-07 09:29:08.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

appreciate any help!!

Comment: Can you show us the StackTrace please?

Comment: Did you log and see the values of v, v.getId(), R.id.btnSearch?

Comment: try `View view =(View) v.getParent();` then `view.findVIewById`

Comment: brilliant !!!! tx, it's working (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are passing `TextView` as an arguement for the `doSearch` method. And you are getting the `EditText` by using `TextView` so obviously `editText` is `null`

I guess this line is causing NPE

```
String query =  editSearch.getText().toString();
```

Try this..for fetching the `EditText`

```
View parent =(View) v.getParent(); 
EditText editSearch = (EditText) parent.findViewById(R.id.editSearch);
```

Comment: i'm not sure i understand your question...i want that when the user will be able to activate the search without the button.

Answer (score 0):

you are casting the view in your function to an EditText and you are passing TextView in OnClick try this `doSearch((EditText)v);`

Comment: i did try this, and it's not working, but tx forthe effort (:

Answer (score 0):

```
//unsuccessful  call
public void onClick(View v)     
{    
switch (v.getId()) {    
     case R.id.btnSearch:     
        doSearch((TextView) v);//changes      
         break;      
    }     
}
```

In your above code you are passing view as **Textview doSearch((TextView)v)** and in your doSearch method implementation inner  you are casting TextView to EditText this reason arrising NullpointerException( **EditText editSearch = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editSearch);**)

Changes
     doSearch((TextView) v);
to
    doSearch((EditText) v);